# Using an empty delimiter

Tags: java, iteration, delimiter

Code Snippet:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(TEXT FILE);
 in.useDelimiter("");

while(in.hasNext()){
  String input = in.next()
}
```

This is a previous exam question, to read the snippet of code and decide what would actually happen in the program.
I know that whitespace is the default delimiter of the scanner, so I assume if you made the delimiter (" ") then it would act exactly as it would if you didnt have it there.

However, since the delimiter is (""), would it read the whole content of the file in one iteration?

Comment: Did you try running it?

Comment: im working on my tablet at the moment so I dont have access to an IDE

Comment: We are not a JVM, sorry to disappoint you :)

Comment: So rather than waiting, you decided to get someone here to do the work for you?

Comment: Its a past exam question that i'm doing, I only started learning computer science a few months ago, this is not my program its an example.

Comment: Re: "I know that whitespace is the default delimiter of the scanner, I assume if you made the delimiter (' ') then it would act exactly as it would if you didnt have it there": Not at all. Setting the delimiter to *a single space* is not at all the same as setting it to *one or more whitespace characters*. (Note that "whitespace" does not have to be spaces: tabs, newlines, etc. also count.)

Comment: `Scanner` edge case trivia is a dumb thing to put on an exam.

Comment: If you read what I wrote above, I'm working through my tablet as i'm currently travelling, and I was hoping someone would know what would happen off the top of their head, and they could tell me whether my assumption that it reads the whole content of the file in one iteration is correct

Comment: If your tablet lets you post (bad) questions on Stack Overflow, then it lets you compile and run Java code at any of various web-sites, such as [Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/).

Comment: I didnt know there were websites that could compile and run java code, dont worry about it i'll just try out the code there. Thanks for the help ruakh

Answer (score 4):

For the curious, using a `""` delimiter with a Scanner will cause `in.next()` to read each part of the file that is separated by `""`, or in other words `in.next()`returns a one character String each time.  It's running time would be O(n), where n is the number of characters in the file (or the length of the input String).